# History of a combinatoric problem: exchanging numbers by throwing stones

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, math-history

Another user recently asked a question on the Puzzling stack: [Two spies throwing stones into a river](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/625/two-spies-throwing-stones-into-a-river). Suitably generalised, it becomes:

> Two spies (Alice and Bob) need to exchange a message. Each will encode their message as a number from $1$ to $M$ before they meet. They will then meet by the river and communicate secretly by throwing stones.
>
> There will be a pile of $N$ indistinguishable stones at their meeting point. Starting with Alice, they take turns throwing some of the stones into the river: Alice throws some number of stones, then Bob, then Alice again...
>
> Each spy must throw at least one stone on their turn, until all $N$ stones are gone.
>
> They observe all throws and separate when there are no more stones. No information is exchanged except the number of stones thrown on each turn.
>
> Given that $N$ is known in advance, what is the largest possible value of $M$?

There is a simple algorithm to compute the answer, and I'm working on a proof of correctness for a more subtle and efficient approach. However, I'm wondering about the history of this problem. The user who posted it on Puzzling.SE knows only that "*the puzzle was proposed in Oct 2009 by user tatunya (currently inactive) on this russian puzzle site: http://braingames.ru/index.php?path=comments&puzzle=475*". The version given there asks whether $M \ge 1700$ given $N=26$.

Does this puzzle have a name? Can anyone ante-date the posting on braingames.ru? Has any analysis of it been published?

Comment: I expect many who first learn of this puzzle by coming across this question (as did I) would interested in reading your nice $2018$ Eureka paper on it. [Here's](https://archive.org/details/eureka-65/page/89/mode/1up) a link to a copy of it in the Internet Archive.